# How to prevent Chrome from taking up 100% of window height?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I don't have this problem in Firefox or Opera Presto but in Chrome on a page that doesn't have the height specified the body takes up 100% of the window height at all times. So basically this means that if the body content fits in less of the window height there will be space remaining there.

Is there a way to inhibit this behavior and make it collapse relative to the amount of content in the body like it does in the other browsers?

The css body rules are:

```
body {
 width     :840px;
 margin    :7px auto;
 background:#f8f8f8;
 border    :1px solid #888;
```

}

Comment: Do you know, what is the right behavior? If it is less than 100%, you should report it as a bug.

Comment: Chrome does not do that on its own, so without a link or the complete markup, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Comment: Edited the post. I don't have anything in the universal selector.

Comment: can you add a screen shot? Cause mine does not have that behavior unless in one condition -----> You have mistakenly set html tag to height:100%. Simply delete that will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks but I solved it. Looks like Chrome doesn't like a naked body. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the body to float to achieve this effect.

```
body {
   float:left;
}
```

Edit: I see you're using the body as a container element. Maybe it's better if you put all your stuff into a container div and don't style the body at all?

Comment: I have the page centered with auto margins so this doesn't work for me. However it does crunch the height of the page as expected.

Comment: I see you're using the body as a container element. Maybe it's better if you put all your stuff into a container div and don't style the body at all?

Comment: That solved it. Thanks. Edit your post so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that on some pages, like that 404 one, Chrome applies `display:flex;` to the body by default. You can give this a try:

```
body{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have any effect.